# Select2-rails is not working with ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, select2-rails

I have difficulties integrating select2-rails with ActiveAdmin. I followed setup steps on 
Select2-rails Github page: https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails and I added line:

```
//= require select2
```

to *app/assets/javascripts/application.js* and line:

```
*= require select2
```

to *app/assets/stylesheets/application.css*

so I assume when I have page in ActiveAdmin I should be able to add line:

```
$('#add_student_select').select2()
```

to *active_admin.js.coffee*

But its not working. In console I can see following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
(anonymous function)
fire
self.fireWith
jQuery.extend.ready
completed
```

I also followed this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839784/getting-select2-to-work-with-active-admin) which recommends to add this line to `active_admin.css.scss`:

```
body.active_admin {
  @import "select2";
}
```

But then I get following error:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: select2.
```

Do I integrate it correctly? I don't think that ActiveAdmin is able to get even access to the librabry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're adding Select2 to the ActiveAdmin interface, you must add the javascript and styles to the ActiveAdmin assets:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js.coffee
#
#= require select2
#
# ...
```

And the stylesheets:

```
// app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss
//
//= require select2
//
// ...
```

In the example you provided, Select2 would be available to the main Rails application, but not ActiveAdmin. ActiveAdmin uses its own javascript and stylesheet files.

Comment: N, I wasn't able to find that. Thank you. I'm overlooked this maybe 50 times. Damn some days are good, and some bad:)

Answer (score 0):

I had met the same issue making select2 work with activeadmin, but instead I used a gem named activeadmin-select2. I had installed it according to the README, but I still got error "File to import not found or unreadable: select2.". It seems like that select2-rails had not been installed or not be accessible, however. So then I tried to add `select2-rails` to my Gemfile, and bundle, lastly, everything went well. You should checked your gem loading before you can make it work.