# Select2 is not showing search option in Drop Down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, select2-rails

I have integrated select2 with my active admin. But it is not working properly. It only showing the drop down without the search option.

I have followed the following link:
([Select2-rails is not working with ActiveAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464109/select2-rails-is-not-working-with-activeadmin))

Used Ruby Version: ruby-2.6.3 [ x86_64 ]
Rails Version:  Rails 5.0.7.2

This is my `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require_tree .
//= require select2
//= require select2_locale_pt-BR
$( "#dropdown" ).select2({
language: "zh-TW"
});
```

This is my `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`

```
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require select2
 *= require select2-bootstrap
```

I have used select2 here,

```
customer_location.input :area, as: :select2, collection: Region.all.map {|u| [u.area.to_s, u.id]}, :input_html => { :class => 'select2-input', :width => 'auto', "data-placeholder" => 'Select Area' }
```

Answer (score 1):

I used [activeadmin-select2](https://github.com/mfairburn/activeadmin-select2) `gem` which worked fine for me.

Add `activeadmin`, `jquery-rails` and `select2-rails` to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'select2-rails'
```

And add `activeadmin-select2` to your Gemfile:

`gem 'activeadmin-select2', github: 'mfairburn/activeadmin-select2'`

Add the activeadmin-select2 calls to the active_admin stylesheets and javascripts with:

`@import "active_admin/select2/base";` `#add this line to your app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss`

`#= require active_admin/select2` `#add this line to your app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js`

**Usage:**

**Filters**

Standard :select filters will automagically be converted to Select2 filters. If you want a multi-select combo-box then use:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Products do
      filter :fruits, as: :select2_multiple, collection: [:apples, :bananas, :oranges]
   end
```

**Select Lists**

To use a Select2 style list simply change from :select to :select2 or :select2_multiple

```
ActiveAdmin.register Products do
     form do |f|
       f.input :fruit, as: :select2
     end
     form do |f|
       f.inputs "Product" do
         f.has_many :fruits, allow_destroy: true, new_record: "Add Fruit" do |e|
           e.input :fruit, as: :select2_multiple
         end
       end
     end
   end
```

Comment: @ZulqarnainAbbas Please accept my answer with an upvote. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

For me I solve it by appling this gem with select2 gem in the gemfile the search option appears to the dropdown in active admin

```
gem 'activeadmin-searchable_select'
```

in active admin add

```
f.input :address_id, label: "Client Address" , as: :searchable_select, :collection => Address.order(name: :desc).to_a(&:name).collect {|address| [address.name, address.id] }
```