# Rails app: File to import not found or unreadable: select2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've inherited a Rails app and am currently being defeated by the above error. The weird thing is this codebase is running on Heroku without this error, so I don't know how.

Here is the full error output:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: select2.

Load paths:
  /app/app/assets/javascripts
  /app/app/assets/stylesheets
  /app/app/assets/widget_javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/coffee-rails-5.0.0/lib/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-searchable_select-1.5.0/app/assets/javascript
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-searchable_select-1.5.0/app/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/select2-rails-4.0.13/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/select2-rails-4.0.13/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin_quill_editor-0.3.4/app/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin_quill_editor-0.3.4/app/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-2.9.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-2.9.0/app/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activeadmin-2.9.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/jquery-rails-4.4.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/formtastic-4.0.0/app/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actioncable-6.1.4.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/activestorage-6.1.4.1/app/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionview-6.1.4.1/lib/assets/compiled
  /app/node_modules):
    2: <html>
    3:   <head>
    4:     <title><%= yield :title_tag %></title>
    5:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
    6:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    7:     <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    8:   </head>

app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss:5
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5
I, [2022-05-04T10:39:06.704054 #20]  INFO -- : source=rack-timeout id=af5eb0c9-e88d-4992-9895-90fa372b4f73 timeout=15000ms service=1506ms state=completed
```

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23548540/1352288), and consequently added `require` references to select2 in the following files:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss
app/assets/javascripts/application.js
app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js
```

...e.g. in `active_admin.scss` I've added

```
//= require select2
```

Someone also said the `config.assets.compile` setting may be relevant here. In my environment file, it's commented-out.

```
  # config.assets.compile = false
```

Here's how I'm starting the app (via Docker):

```
gem install bundler -v 2.2.21 && bundle install && rails db:migrate && rails server --port 3000 --binding 0.0.0.0
```

And here's my `Gemfile` (there's no mention of select2 in it, but it *does* feature in the `Gemfile.lock`, most likely because it's a dependency of another Gem, namely `activeadmin-searchable_select`.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.7.5'

gem 'activeadmin', '2.9.0'
gem 'activeadmin_quill_editor'
gem 'active_reporting'
gem 'activeadmin-searchable_select'
gem 'active_admin_import'
gem 'api_guard'
gem 'apipie-rails'
gem 'azure-storage-blob', require: false
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'blind_index'
gem 'browser'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'devise'
gem 'emoji_flag'
gem 'forecast_io'
gem 'flag_shih_tzu'
gem 'groupdate'
gem 'i18n-active_record', github: 'svenfuchs/i18n-active_record', require: 'i18n/active_record'
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'feedjira'
gem 'httparty', '0.18.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jwt'
gem 'lockbox'
gem 'pg'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rails', '6.1.4.1'
gem 'rack-cors'
gem 'rack-timeout'
gem 'redis'
gem 'rollbar'
gem 'rqrcode'
gem 'rubyzip'
gem 'ruby-openai'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sinatra', require: nil # if you require 'sinatra' you get the DSL extended to Object
gem 'slack-notifier'
gem 'slim' # slim and Sinatra are for the Sidekiq web ui
gem 'will_paginate'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
  gem 'mini_racer', github: 'sqreen/mini_racer', branch: 'use-libv8-node'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: :test
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'listen'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'rubocop'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '2.0.1'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'ffaker'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '4.0.0.rc1'
end
```

---- EDIT ----

`active_admin.js` (top of):

```
//= require active_admin/base
//= require active_admin/searchable_select
//= require activeadmin/quill_editor/quill
//= require activeadmin/quill_editor_input
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of active_admin.js ?

Comment: See edit. Assume you need just the top part, which handles the require. Select2 should be coming in as a dependency of searchable_select. That's what the Gemfile.lock says.

Comment: Are you requiring select_2 anywhere ? Maybe try requiring it in active_admin.js before the //= require active_admin/searchable_select line ?

Comment: select2 is not being required anywhere explicitly - I did a project-wide search for "select2" and nothing. So it's just a dependency of searchable_select. The weird thing is this is all working fine on the prod server - it's only when I try to run everything locally these errors happen.

Comment: Maybe just try though, I can't think of anything else so better cross it off at least

Comment: Also - are you certain there are no JS errors on production on that part of the admin?

Comment: Not fully certain, but what I do know is the app is working live. When I set it up locally, any such errors are fatal and cause the app to go down, so presumably the app wouldn't be live in production if those same errors were happening there. I tried explicitly require'ing select2 in `active_admin.js` but same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244505/discussion-between-joel-blum-and-mitya).