# why summernote-rails on activeadmin output not working (button are rendered but its everywhere)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

**admin.scss**

```
 /*
  *= require bootstrap  
  *= require summernote
 */
```

**active_admin.js.coffee**

```
 #= require jquery
 #= require bootstrap
 #= require summernote

 $ ->
   $('[data-provider="summernote"]').each ->
    $(this).summernote()
    height: 280
    enter code here
```

**post.rb**

```
   form do |f|
  f.inputs 'Blog Post' do
  f.input :title
  f.input :featured_image
  f.input :body, input_html: { 'data-provider' => "summernote"}
  f.input :user_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: current_admin_user.id}
  end
  f.actions
 end
```

I managed to run the *summernote-rails* in the *activeadmin*, but the button and options are all over the page. style for the summernote-rails is not working properly. how can i solve this?

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: sorry i miss the "why" . sorry my English is not good .

Comment: Welcome to SO by the way. You may be interested in reading the following documentation about [how preferably asking here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you need to wrap the css in body.active_admin, see for example  [Getting select2 to work with active admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839784/getting-select2-to-work-with-active-admin)